# Multiple parameters implements in Symfony2 routing

Tags: php, symfony, routes

Here is normal `GET` request URL

```
http://localhost/person.php?name='Jack'&age=25&gender='male'
```

How to implement it to Symfony2 routing?

---

After test here is my solution:

```
acme_person_info:
    pattern:  /person/name/{name}/age/{age}/gender/{gender}
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeUserBundle:Person:info }
```

---

```
class PersonController extends Controller
{
    public function infoAction($name, $age, $gender) 
    {
             // do something here
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should read the symfony doc anyway. see http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

```
// app/config/routing.yml
person:
    path:      /person/{name}-{age}-{gender}
    defaults:  { _controller: AcmeBlogBundle:Person:index }

// src/Acme/BlogBundle/Controller/PersonController.php
namespace Acme\BlogBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name, $age, $gender)
    {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could access query parameter in Request object.

```
$request->query->get('query_parameter_name_here');
```

For example,

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class PersonController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        // retrieve query parameter with $request
        $person = $request->query->get('name');
        $age = $request->query->get('age');
    }
}
```

Note that,

For GET /person, you access the `query` attribute

```
$request->query
```

For POST /person, you access the `request` attribute

```
$request->request
```